# No retrieval of html by urllib2 and request both libraries

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to retrieve  the list of urls from the countries given in this website 
https://www.zain.com/en/?home=home

In this if we inspect the element 'English', there is a list of urls of each and every country which I want to retrieve

I have written following code for this in beutiful soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import json
import io
import sys
#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


Main_url='https://www.zain.com/en/?home=home';
response=requests.get(Main_url,verify=False);

body=response.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(body,'html.parser')
#print soup
Country_Url_list=soup.find('ul',attrs={"class":"lnklist clearfix"})
print Country_Url_list
```

I have also tried urllib2 for the same But it is not retrieving a single t html tags thats why `Country_Url_list` is returning null.Where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code. You don't get anything beacuse when executing `response.text` redirection happens:

```
"<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>\n<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>\n...
```

Comment: So whats the solution BS requires text as input?

Comment: What about urllib2 same thiing happens in it too?

Comment: urllib throws out same redirection.
It's a real issue here=)

Answer (score 0):

The Page your scraping looks like dynamic page. instead of urllib you should use `selenium` after that are able to retrieve urls. Happy coding :)